# No permission to my Google Drive foldrer

Tags: permissions, directory

After installing google drive on Ubuntu 14.04, the google drive folder it created does not allow me to put my own files into the folder. In the permissions tab the folders owner is down as root.

Comment: Please post output of `sudo stat /path/to/google-drive/directory`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it your own, try this (change yourusername and yourgroup to match you, `id` will help):

`sudo chown yourusername.yourgroup /path/to/google-drive/directory`

Or you can make it writeable by you with:

`sudo chmod 777 /path/to/google-drive/directory`